# Spring boot test, @WithMockUser produce NPE in Controller method

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, java-17

i have an issue with my controller test

So my base test class configured like so

```
@SpringBootTest
@WithMockUser(username = "test_user",authorities = "Configured_allacess_authority")
public abstract class BaseControllerTest extends DatabaseIT {

protected static long counter;

protected MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
@Autowired
protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;
protected MockRestServiceServer restServiceServer;
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@BeforeEach
protected void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .build();
    restServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
}
```

and test code

```
        mockMvc.perform(request)
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
           .andExpect(content().json(s));
```

When i debugging my controller method which is

```
        public ResponseEntity<?> getSomething (
    @Parameter(description = "ID") final String id,
    @ApiIgnore @AuthenticationPrincipal Authentication user){
        ////
    }
```

user value is null, though when i invoke         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() here in controller i'm getting Authentication object that's refers to one i mocked in

```
@WithMockUser(username = "test_user",authorities = "Configured_allacess_authority")
```

So recently i've updated my project to Java 17 , that also forced me to update spring boot to

version: '2.5.5'

and spring cloud to

"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.5"

Comment: did you try `@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal user`?

Comment: @Antoniossss, just tried , still null :(

Comment: Remove the `MockMvc` setup from the `setup` method and just use `@Autowired` on the `MockMvc` field.

Comment: @M.Deinum, still null, also added  `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`, because  `@Autowired MockMvc` does not work without this annotation

Comment: I would also suggest to use version 2.5.14 (the latest of the 2.5.x line instead of some in between version). Also officially Spring Boot 2.5.7 and up support Java17.

Comment: @M.Deinum, upgrading spring to 2.5.14 had no effect unfortunately